# Получить и принять «trade offers» (Steam Web API)

Tags: php, steam-web-api, steam

Здравствуйте. Только начал изучать Steam Web API, информации мало.

Хотел узнать, как с его помощью получить входящие предложения обмена и принять их?
Вот есть статья [Steam Web API/IEconService](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API/IEconService), но мне самому в ней разобраться сложно.

Answer (score 2):

Данная API не предоставляет возможность принятия входящего предложения обмена.

С помощью нее можно лишь получить список предложений, отменить собственные, либо дать отказ на входящие. При этом она работает только для аккаунта, на который у тебя зарегистрирована API естественно.

Пример запроса для получения списка предложений:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/GetTradeOffers/v1/?key=********&get_sent_offers=1&time_historical_cutoff=100
```

Подставляешь нужные тебе параметры, что описаны в мануале, и api ключ в место звездочек

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/' . $tradeID . '/accept';
$partnerID = '';
$tradeID = '';
 $data = array(
        'sessionid' => $sessionId,
        'serverid' => '1',
        'partner' => $partnerID,
        'tradeofferid' => tradeID,
        'captcha' => ''
    );
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookies);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Referer: https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/' . $tradeID));
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, strtoupper('POST'));
    $response = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
    echo $response;
```

$TradeID можно найти отправив Get запрос на http://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/GetTradeOffers/v1/?key=[API_KEY]&get_received_offers=1&time_historical_cutoff=100 ;
$sessionID и $cookies берем из авторизации.

Answer (score 0):

Данная API позволяет Вам получить трейд-оффера, как и их id-шники. Собсна принять их можно простым Post-запросом на `https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/"tradeId"/accept` где tradeId - собственно, ID оффера.

В шапке отправки нужно указать:

```
{"sessionid", ...},
{"serverid", ...},
{"tradeofferid", ...},
{"partner", ...},
{"captcha", ...}
```

Первые два параметры должны храниться в контейнере, который собирается при авторизации. Третий и четвертый параметры, будут получены через предложенный вами API, а Капча, по умолчанию, `string.empty`