# Steam api. Принять предложение обмена

Tags: javascript, steam-web-api

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как принять предложение обмена программно ?
Все чего я смог достичь, так это найти активные предложение и вытащить их id. Но как можно реализовать принятие этих предложений ? Знаю что это возможно, очень много сайтов с такой системой, но, к сожалению, информации об этом нигде абсолютно нету. Может кто-то помочь ?

P.S. Делаю приложение для  Google Chrome, так что про авторизацию думать не нужно.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/415186/16095

Comment: Вопрос не именно про api стима. Как средствами javascript реализовать данную идею ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собсна принять их можно простым Post-запросом на https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/`"tradeId"`/accept где `tradeId` - собственно, ID оффера.

В шапке отправки нужно указать:

```
{"sessionid", ...},
{"serverid", ...},
{"tradeofferid", ...},
{"partner", ...},
{"captcha", ...}
```

Первые два параметра должны храниться в контейнере, который собирается при авторизации. Третий и четвертый параметры, будут получены через `IEconService`, а Капча, по умолчанию, string.empty